# Call Sql statements containing declarative block and executable block using Jpa Entitymanager

Tags: java, sql, jpa, entitymanager

I need to call the sql script containing declarative block and executable block in Java.
We are using JPA. And we can not create stored procedure on DATABASE.

```
DECLARE
    ....
BEGIN
   ....
END;
```

Comment: This might help
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-stored-procedures

Comment: Actually , the DB stored procedure wont work, its not an option for me. I have to use java code to execute the sql statements